# Appendchild error parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' in Javascript . Not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a value **res.rating.value** and I want to show font awesome stars for this value. Like if the value is 2 then 2 stars will show in the div. I have the following code but whenever I run it the appendChild function shows the error failed to execute parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

```
 if (res.rating.value != null) {
     
   note.innerHTML = `<i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>`;
     for (i = 0; i < res.rating.value; i++) {
       note.appendChild(
         (document.createElement("p").innerHTML = `<i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>`)
       );
     }
    
  } else {
    note.innerHTML = `not rated`;
  }
```

please take a look and help me find the solution

Comment: Where do you define `note`? Please update your code to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `appendChild` expects the first parameter being a node, you're passing a string. Create the `p` element outside of the loop, and append a clone: `note.appendChild(p.cloneNode(true));`.

Comment: `document.createElement("p").innerHTML = '<i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>'` doesn't return an element. It will return the string `'<i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>'`

Comment: @Reyno note is a div id and I access it by document.getElementbyid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I tried the following code and it worked

```
if (res.rating.value != null) {
    for (i = 0; i < res.rating.value; i++) {
      const p = document.createElement("span");
      p.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-star"></i>`;
      note.appendChild(p);
    }
  } else {
    note.innerHTML = `not rated`;
  }
```